# Sprint Lg Optimus Driver

Tags: android, driver, app-inventor

I am having great deal of trouble trying to find the driver needed for the Lg Optimus (Sprint) so that I can begin using App Inventor program. I connect my phone but no notifications show that it is connected, only charging. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out.

*edit* Any details would be useful even if it's just to say that you are having trouble as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time last night connecting my LG GT540 to the PC. I installed the driver and PC Suite from LG's super crappy [website](http://www.lg.com/uk/support/product/support-product.jsp). Make sure you go to your contry's LG website as it cannot auto detect where you are accessing the site from and redirect to a specific country's site.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful when having problems connecting a phone to use the barcode when not fighting to get the phone connected.

The dropdown in the upper right
  Package for Phone->Show Barcode

It will generate a QR code you can scan with your phone and then you can load the app to test.